# Commerceguys/addressing missing locality in for some countries

Tags: 9

I spent the weekend digging into this one. Pretty sure that the issue is a bug (or missing data) from https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing

I've installed a clean version of Drupal 9.3.6
Installed address module 8.x-1.10
Commerceguys/addressing v1.2.2

Added "address" as a field to a new (and only node).

Some countries display locality (e.g., state/province) others don't. I've filed a report in the issue queue [(here)](https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing/issues/168), but wondering if anyone has encountered this and if so if there is a workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Address module uses the [Addressing](https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing) library to display localities.

After installing the Address module, you can find the actual locality data here:

`/vendor/commerceguys/addressing/resources/subdivision/COUNTRY-CODE.json`

Where `COUNTRY-CODE` is the two-letter ISO code for that country.

As for 2-2022, Italy (`IT`) has data, but France (`FR`) does not.

You can easily create data for additional countries yourself.  All you need to do is use one of the existing files as an example and get a list of ISO codes for the localities in question.  Then you can add your JSON data as a PR to the addressing repo and hopefully it can get included for everyone.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. You confirmed my suspicions and provided the best possible solution.